# Extract Data from JSON Array and Merge with Parent Attribute that is not an array

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist, apache-nifi

I have the following **JSON**

```
{
  "ARTGEntryJsonResult": {
    "AnnualChargeExemptWaverDate": null
    "Conditions": [
      ""
    ],
    "ConsumerInformation": {
      "DocumentLink": ""
    },
    "EntryType": "Medicine",
    "LicenceClass": "",
    "LicenceId": "152567"
    },
    "Products": [
      {
        "AdditionalInformation": [],
        "Components": [
          {
            "DosageForm": "Drug delivery system, transdermal",
            "RouteOfAdministration": "Transdermal",
            "VisualIdentification": "Dull, homogenous"
          }
        ],
        "Containers": [
          {
            "Closure": "",
            "Conditions": [
              "Store at room temperature"
            ],
            "LifeTime": "2 Years",
            "Material": null,
            "Temperature": "Store below 25 degrees Celsius",
            "Type": "Sachet"
          }
        ],
        "EffectiveDate": "2017-09-18",
        "GMDNCode": "",
        "GMDNTerm": "",
        "Ingredients": [
          {
            "Name": "Fentanyl",
            "Strength": "6.3000 mg"
          }
        ],
        "Name": "FENTANYL SANDOZ ",
        "Packs": [
          {
            "PoisonSchedule": "(S8) Controlled Drug",
            "Size": "1"
          },
          {
            "PoisonSchedule": "(S8) Controlled Drug",
            "Size": "10"
          },
          {
            "PoisonSchedule": "(S8) Controlled Drug",
            "Size": "2"
          },
          {
            "PoisonSchedule": "(S8) Controlled Drug",
            "Size": "3"
          },
          {
            "PoisonSchedule": "(S8) Controlled Drug",
            "Size": "4"
          },
          {
            "PoisonSchedule": "(S8) Controlled Drug",
            "Size": "5"
          },
          {
            "PoisonSchedule": "(S8) Controlled Drug",
            "Size": "7"
          },
          {
            "PoisonSchedule": "(S8) Controlled Drug",
            "Size": "8"
          }
        ],
        "SpecificIndications": [
          "Management of chronic pain requiring opioid analgesia."
        ],
        "StandardIndications": [],
        "Type": "Single Medicine Product",
        "Warnings": []
      }
    ],

  }
}
```

I am able to extract it using the **splitJson** + **EvaluateJsonPath** but i get the Array Fields Data in a single row.

Example of what i managed to get considering this JSON file:

**LicenceId Name PoisonSchedule Size**

```
152567 FENTANYL SANDOZ "(S8) Controlled Drug","(S8) Controlled Drug","(S8) Controlled Drug" 1,10,2
```

**What i actually want is :**

**LicenceId Name PoisonSchedule Size**

```
152567 FENTANYL SANDOZ (S8) Controlled Drug 1

152567 FENTANYL SANDOZ (S8) Controlled Drug 10

152567 FENTANYL SANDOZ (S8) Controlled Drug 2
```

Any ideas are much appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: not clear what you want. do you want to convert json to plain text?